# strange problem updating shared preferences setting

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android app. There is a screen where I want to be able to allow the user to save an unknown amount of Strings 
that will later appear in a menu. I am doing this by creating and updating a stringset using `SharedPreferences`.

**Problem:**
It seems to work fine until I move to a different activity where for some reason the stringset *presets* stored in shared `preferences` now only contain the first string stored. When I am in the activity where I create/update
the shared preferences stringset *presets* it contains all of them.

Below is my code for:

- Creating/updating the stringset(and logging that it exists)
- Logging it exists in a second activity
- Logging messages showing the contents of the stringset in the original and second activity

  ```
  public void bSave(View view) {

          Set<String> presets;

          Integer HOR_RES = Integer.parseInt(editTextHor.getText().toString());
          Integer VERT_RES = Integer.parseInt(editTextVert.getText().toString());
          String str = (editTextTitle.getText().toString()+HOR_RES + "x" + VERT_RES);



      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Share", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      SharedPreferences.Editor edit = settings.edit();



      presets = settings.getStringSet("presets", new HashSet<String>());
      presets.add(str);
      Log.e("f                  u", presets.toString());

      edit.putStringSet("presets",presets);
      edit.apply();
      Log.e("f                  u", settings.getStringSet("presets", new HashSet<String>()).toString());


  }
  ```

AND

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Share", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Set<String> strings = settings.getStringSet("presets", new HashSet<String>());      
Log.e("f                  u", settings.getStringSet("presets", new HashSet<String>()).toString());
```

AND

```
2018-11-29 13:37:53.107 12030-12030/screenresizerpremiumv2.andrewdaw.com.screenresizerpremium E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!
2018-11-29 13:37:53.110 12030-12030/screenresizerpremiumv2.andrewdaw.com.screenresizerpremium E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!
2018-11-29 13:37:53.755 12030-12053/screenresizerpremiumv2.andrewdaw.com.screenresizerpremium E/vndksupport: Could not load vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so from sphal namespace: dlopen failed: library "vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so" not found.
2018-11-29 13:37:53.782 12030-12030/screenresizerpremiumv2.andrewdaw.com.screenresizerpremium E/f                  u: []
2018-11-29 13:38:11.938 12030-12030/screenresizerpremiumv2.andrewdaw.com.screenresizerpremium E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2018-11-29 13:38:11.938 12030-12030/screenresizerpremiumv2.andrewdaw.com.screenresizerpremium E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2018-11-29 13:38:11.974 12030-12030/screenresizerpremiumv2.andrewdaw.com.screenresizerpremium E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2018-11-29 13:38:18.235 12030-12030/screenresizerpremiumv2.andrewdaw.com.screenresizerpremium E/f                  u: [11x1]
2018-11-29 13:38:21.548 12030-12030/screenresizerpremiumv2.andrewdaw.com.screenresizerpremium E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2018-11-29 13:38:21.581 12030-12030/screenresizerpremiumv2.andrewdaw.com.screenresizerpremium E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2018-11-29 13:38:21.581 12030-12030/screenresizerpremiumv2.andrewdaw.com.screenresizerpremium E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2018-11-29 13:38:21.638 12030-12030/screenresizerpremiumv2.andrewdaw.com.screenresizerpremium E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2018-11-29 13:38:21.638 12030-12030/screenresizerpremiumv2.andrewdaw.com.screenresizerpremium E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
2018-11-29 13:38:26.323 12030-12030/screenresizerpremiumv2.andrewdaw.com.screenresizerpremium E/f                  u: [22x2, 11x1]
2018-11-29 13:38:26.324 12030-12030/screenresizerpremiumv2.andrewdaw.com.screenresizerpremium E/f                  u: [22x2, 11x1]
```

AND

```
2018-11-29 13:38:45.544 12289-12289/? E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!
2018-11-29 13:38:45.546 12289-12289/? E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!
2018-11-29 13:38:46.214 12289-12329/? E/vndksupport: Could not load vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so from sphal namespace: dlopen failed: library "vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so" not found.
2018-11-29 13:38:46.255 12289-12289/screenresizerpremiumv2.andrewdaw.com.screenresizerpremium E/f                  u: [11x1]
```

Comment: Have you tried to make shared preferences object singleton? When you call apply OS starts an asynchronous task to save it to disk so if you start next activity immediately it is possible that newly created object returns some old data. Try singleton (using dagger or a simple static field)

Comment: @Armin It doesnt matter if I wait. Even if I completely close the app and restart it the shared preference only contains the original string and not the second one. This is also true for restarting and going to the screen where i update the the stringset. It appears that the second string is not actually persisting in the shared preferences between activitys / app closes. I cant figure out why though.

Answer (score 0):

I actually run to same issues before until i met a well made library and requires not much and mad my code much good looking , FastSave: https://github.com/yehiahd/FastSave-Android
despite the ability to store like normal variables it also can save objects as easy of one line FastSave.getInstance().saveObject(key,customObject); // For Saving Custom Object
Check it out ...

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't figure it out so just did this instead

```
public void bSave(View view) {

            Set<String> presets;

            Integer HOR_RES = Integer.parseInt(editTextHor.getText().toString());
            Integer VERT_RES = Integer.parseInt(editTextVert.getText().toString());
            String str = (editTextTitle.getText().toString()+HOR_RES + "x" + VERT_RES);

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Share", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = settings.edit();

            int i = 0;
            while(!settings.getString("preset"+i,"").equals("")){
                i++;
            }

            edit.putString("preset"+i,str);
            edit.apply();


    }
```

Retrieval

```
int i = 0;
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("Share", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);



while(!settings.getString("preset"+i,"").equals("")){
    menu.add(settings.getString("preset"+i,""));
    i++;
}
```